# Can I use `distance` as my class member variable name?

Tags: c++

It would be ok to define a class like this (ignore its implmentation):

```
class MyEngine {
private:
    int*  params;
    int   param_len;
public:
    void  set_params(int* _params, int _len);
    float  get_result(); // relies on `distance` member
    float  distance;   // people can modify this
};
```

However, if using `vector`, assume it implicitly includes `<iterator>` which contains `std::distance`, **how do compiler distinguish `std::distance` and `distance` member? (Or will it cause un-expected crash when run?)**. Say, the function `get_result()` relies `distance` member value.

```cpp
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class MyEngine {
private:
    vector<int> params;
public:
    void  set_params(int* _params, int _len);
    float  get_result(); // relies on `distance` member
    float  distance;   // people can modify this
};
```

---

update

As people mentioned, `using namespace std` is bad practice; however, there are still people writing code with `using namespace std`, and if we are collaborate with them, using their code, is there any concreate example that demonstrate the badness of `using namespace std`, expecially severe run error? This, would be my real purpose.

There is an answer, saying distinguish the two `distance` by type. Let's just try this snippet:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
using namespace std;

class MyEngine {
private:
    vector<int> params;
    float* distance;   // people can modify this
    int len;
public:
    void setup();
};

void MyEngine::setup()
{
    len = 100;
    distance = (float*)malloc(sizeof(float)*len);
    for(int i=0; i<len; i++) {
        distance[0] = len - i;
        params.push_back(len-i);
    }

    int num = distance(params.begin(), params.end());
    printf("distance is: %d\n", num);
}

int main(){

    MyEngine engine;
    int len = 10;
    engine.setup();

    return 0;
}
```

Which, would cause compile error saying:

```
main.cpp:25:23: error: called object type 'float *' is not a function or function pointer
    int num = distance(params.begin(), params.end());
              ~~~~~~~~^
1 error generated.
```

Demonstrates that it can't distinguish the two `distance` from their types.

Comment: See [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/10871073).

Comment: @AdrianMole Thanks, `distance` is mentioned in comments in the reference page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, one is `MyEngine::distance`, and the other is `std::distance`. They're different names. This is the whole point of *scopes*.

There is only a problem if you use the unqualified name `distance` and leave the compiler to figure it out, but if that's not going to work then it'll be because the type of the one chosen doesn't match your usage, so your program won't compile.

If you ever did put things in `std` then the name *can* clash in potentially undiagnosable ways, which *can* cause crashes, and has undefined behaviour per the standard.

Comment: Can you please give a good and short example that can reproduce the "undefined behaviour per the standard"?

Comment: @HaxtraZ `#include <iostream>` `namespace std { void foo() {} }`

Answer (score 1):

The function `distance` has a different type than the member `distance`, so the compiler figures that out by the type.

You can even have a function `distance(...)`. As long as parameters are different, they have different type and the compiler figures that out.

Also note that you should not use `using namespace std` because that also irritates the human reader.

In your updated example, the compiler is indeed confused. You can specify that you want to use the `distance` function in this case by changing it to `int num = std::distance(...);`

Comment: Even if the type were the same, it would not be a problem.

Comment: @Henk I've updated my question with a new test code